# how to implement AirPrint into an iOS app using swift Xcode 6

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

Im new to making apps and i know a little bit about swift but I was wondering if anyone could help me implement AirPrint into my app. I have looked at apple's developer website but the demo is written in objective C and i am writing my app in swift

Answer (score 0):

Short of learning to read Objective-C (which I recommend you do, since it doesn't take too long), you can use [this](http://objectivec2swift.net/#/converter) website to convert the code. It's not perfect, but it should guide you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Swift 4 code for printing text:

```
func print(text: String) {

    let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.shared

    let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary: nil)
    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputType.general
    printController.printInfo = printInfo

    let format = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: textWithNewCarriageReturns)

    format.perPageContentInsets.top = 72
    format.perPageContentInsets.bottom = 72
    format.perPageContentInsets.left = 72
    format.perPageContentInsets.right = 72
    printController.printFormatter = format

    printController.present(animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Alternatively, if you have a long string with multiple \n carriage returns, you need to first replace all of the \n occurrences with br / before submitting the string to the UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter. Here is an example for Swift 4:

```
func print(text: String) {
    let textWithNewCarriageReturns = text.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "<br />")

    let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.shared

    let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary: nil)
    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputType.general
    printController.printInfo = printInfo

    let format = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: textWithNewCarriageReturns)

    format.perPageContentInsets.top = 72
    format.perPageContentInsets.bottom = 72
    format.perPageContentInsets.left = 72
    format.perPageContentInsets.right = 72
    printController.printFormatter = format

    printController.present(animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
}
```